# applying beta-reduction (call func that returns func) to get an abstraction (function) in python

Tags: python, lambda, lambda-calculus

I wrote a simple example of what im trying to do :

```
class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def mul(x,y):
        return x*y
    FUNC1 = staticmethod(lambda y: Test.mul(y,2))
    FUNC2 = staticmethod(lambda y: staticmethod(lambda x: Test.mul(y,x)))
print Test.FUNC1(2)
print Test.FUNC2(2)(3)
```

> ```
> print Test.FUNC2(2)(3)
> ```
>
> TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable

I was expecting second line to print 6 (as 3*2), how to do that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well that was easier then i thought :

```
class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def mul(x,y):
        return x*y
    FUNC1 = staticmethod(lambda y: Test.mul(y,2))
    FUNC2 = staticmethod(lambda y: lambda x: Test.mul(y,x))
print Test.FUNC1(2)
print Test.FUNC2(2)(3)
```

this works

Answer (score 0):

you are evaluating the `lambda function`; instead you should `return` it:

```
class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def mul(x,y):
        return x*y

    @staticmethod
    def FUNC2(y):
        return lambda y: Test.mul(y,2)
```

which gives:

```
print(Test.FUNC2(2))  # <function Test.FUNC1.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f2c92594a60>
print(Test.FUNC2(2)(3))  # 6
```

---

a different way to go is to use [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools):

```
from operator import mul
from functools import partial

class Test:

    @staticmethod
    def FUNC2(y):
        return partial(mul, y)
    # or
    # FUNC2 = staticmethod(lambda y: partial(mul, y))

print(Test.FUNC2(2))  # functools.partial(<built-in function mul>, 2)
print(Test.FUNC2(2)(3)) # 6
```

Comment: Test.FUNC1(2) works as expected, its Test.FUNC2 that doesnt work... this answer is irrelevant...

Comment: @OfekRon oh, i mislabeled the function in both examples. fixed now... you had no issues with `FUNC1`, right?